# Php 5.5 change password

Tags: php, passwords

**EDIT:** Inside the config.php I create and maintain the session. As well as through that connect to MySQL.

I am trying to learn how to use PHP 5.5 Password_hash and password_verify as more of a learning experience then anything else, I havent been doing this too long and this is the first time I have had to ask a question here (usually someone has already asked my question)

So here is my problem.

I can get password_hash and password_verify to work fine when I register and log in. But for some reason when I use a script for changing passwords, I can no longer log in.

Relavent code snippets:

Register:

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);

$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$sql = 'INSERT INTO Staff (username, password) ' .
"VALUES ('$username', '$hashed_password')";

mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() );

?>
```

RegisterHTML:

```
<div id="login-content">
<form action="register.php" method="post">
<fieldset id="inputs">
<div class="label"></div><input type="text" name="username"/><br />
<div class="label"></div><input type="password" name="password"/><br />
</fieldset>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
</div>
```

ChangePwd:

```
<?php
include('config.php');

$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['newPassword']);
$password2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['confirmPassword']);
$username = ($_SESSION['username']);


if ($password <> $password2) { 
echo "Your passwords do not match.";
}
else if ($password === $password2){

$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


$sql = "UPDATE Staff SET password='$hashed_password' WHERE username='$username'";

mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() );
}
else { mysqli_error($con); }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

ChangePwdHTML:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
?>
<div id="login-content">
<form action="changePassword.php" method="post">
<fieldset id="inputs">
<div class="label"></div><input type="password" name="passwordNew"/><br />
<div class="label"></div><input type="password" name="passwordConfirm"/><br />
</fieldset>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Change Password" />
</form>
</div>
```

Connect:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['username']));
        $password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);

    $sql = ('SELECT password,id,rank FROM Staff WHERE username="'.$username.'"');
    $req = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() );
    $dn = mysql_fetch_assoc($req);
    $hash = $dn['password'];

    if(password_verify($password, $hash))
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['userid'] = $dn['id'];
        $_SESSION['rank'] = $dn['rank'];
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['username']));
        $password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
?>
```

I am sure my code is pretty messy, and some of it is dated... its kind of... franken-code at this point, built from various examples and tutorials I found.

Comment: I see some mysqli in there as well, you cannot combine that with mysql. But you should really switch everything to mysqli or PDO and use prepared statements.

Comment: PHP 5.5 does not support `mysql_` functions. Plus, it's unclear if you've started the session or not.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Nah, it'll just bug you with warnings ;-)

Comment: @jeroen I'm running Wamp with 5.5 and those don't work at all.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Seriously? They have just been deprecated but they should be there. I don't use windows though...

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hmmmmmm, `**Warning** This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future.`. Must be your computer then :-)

Comment: @jeroen Must be; *lucky me* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Very true!

Comment: @jeroen Wondering if OP even started the session. I asked, but no response.

Comment: I responded. I edited the top of my post.
Sorry, I am at work so things are slow.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think he has, otherwise the password would not change at all.

Comment: @jeroen Then it could be in their HTML form then. Could be anything.

Comment: *Woahhhhhh* they're mixing MySQL APIs @jeroen in ChangePwd - who knows which one they're using to connect with also.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hahaha, see the very first comment...

Comment: @OP: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. @jeroen sorry, my bad.

Comment: Too many unknowns to give a proper answer. Show us your HTML form relevant to change password.

Comment: Okay hold on im trying to make the suggested changes as fast as I can.

Comment: `name="passwordConfirm"` and `$_POST['confirmPassword']` that's the problem same for the other one too `name="passwordNew"` and `$_POST['newPassword']`  you inverted the words.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah, that kind of complicates things...

Comment: @jeroen *Errrrr,* yeah kinda ;-)

Comment: @FrankEdgar Always do `var_dump()`'s of the variables in question to see if they are what they should be.

Comment: Having used error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have signaled "Undefined index...." for both. [Something I pointed out earlier...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495967/php-5-5-change-password#comment47151565_29495967)

Comment: Oi. Thats a glaring mistake. Its always something like that...
I just added the 
   error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
And I was going through the errors when you posted.

Comment: @FrankEdgar So, problem solved?

Comment: Well, that was fun :-)

Comment: Let me check. I have 11 errors/notices/warnings I have to parse through.
Thanks for everyones help though. Ill post in a few minutes if it worked.
I really am trying to modernize my code. I was starting with proper password handling, but I guess I should start with Mysqli

Comment: @FrankEdgar I've made an edit to Jeroen's answer outlining my findings and taken from my comment. If it did in fact fix it, you should consider accepting the answer. No sense in me putting one in ;-)

Comment: That did fix it. I started fixing those errors. I have issues with my using Headers for redirects, and the mysql functions being depreciated. Ect. I guess I will start googling. 

@jeroen I looked at what you posted, the php.net manual is often helpful, but I dont understand what all that is. Im still in the phase where every time my code actually works, I feel like its magic.

Comment: @FrankEdgar I know how you feel :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to see what the exact problem is but a potential problem is that you are processing the passwords in different ways when you register / change your password and when you check: You use `mysql_real_escape_string` when you set it but `strip_slashes` when you compare it.

That would cause passwords that contain quotes or slashes not to match when you try to login.

You should not touch the user's password at all because a password can contain slashes, quotes, etc.

Instead, you should switch to PDO or mysqli and use prepared statements and don't change the user's input except when you validate for example a new user-name.

---

`name="passwordConfirm"` and `$_POST['confirmPassword']` that's one of the problems, and the same for the other one also `name="passwordNew"` and `$_POST['newPassword']` you inverted the words.

Having used error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have signaled "Undefined index...." for both.

Comment: I have updated them to all be the same.
If I dont escape certain special characters arent I opening myself up to a security risk?

Comment: @FrankEdgar As in nothing at all? If you are going to hash it, there is no point in preparing it for the database before you do that :-)

Comment: @FrankEdgar That is why you should use prepared statements. But if you have to escape your data, you do that right before you insert it in the database, not before you hash it.

Comment: So I dont need to use any kind of sterilization on passwords? I was under the general impression that you sterilze any use input.

Edit: Didnt see your last message. I dont really know what prepared statements are. The older syntax has the best tutorials so that is what I am using.

Comment: @FrankEdgar The older syntax is deprecated, will generate warnings now and be removed from php in the future. Best to do it right from the start. But still, if you need to escape it, you do that right before you insert it, for usernames, passwords, etc.

Comment: Do you have any resources on the newer stuff? Examples, tutorials, anything I can take apart and see how it works?

Comment: @FrankEdgar I think the examples in the manual are not bad: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php. And of course here on SO :-)

Comment: @jeroen [This doesn't help...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29495967/php-5-5-change-password#comment47152005_29495967) no match.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Fred for moderator!

Comment: @jeroen Thanks for the nomination. But, 1/2 hour a day each day... *hm....*, not sure I'm ready to fill those shoes ;-)

Comment: @jeroen I'd call that green ticky an "assist" ;-) Glad to see this was resolved; *cheers*. Oh, I'll take mine with just a bit of milk; *grazie*.

Comment: @jeroen I don't mind; I actually enjoy it cold. ;-) Keep it "on ice" for me.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you both for your help. I am going to start googling PDO (I dont really know what PDO stands for, so Ill start there.)

Comment: @Fred-ii- After Reading a bit, PDO makes sense because it can be used across multiple databases, But Mysqli is very similar to mysql. Can I use mysqli for now until I get more used to it?

Comment: @FrankEdgar Sure you can. Just as long as you use prepared statements; *they're safer* ;-)

Comment: @FrankEdgar Of course, but personally I find mysqli harder to use than PDO.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I see things like $stmt and I have to wonder, does everyone just use the same variable? Or is that a predefined one? I looked for a list of predefined functions for mysqli and it doesnt look like there is one out there, so I have no idea why everyone is using the same variables like $db and $stmt ect. Just best practices or is there something more?

Comment: @FrankEdgar You can use anything you want. But that's an example which is used by most. Just as long as you change all instances of `$stmt` to the variable you'll be using.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I am at a loss. I sort of understand the general idea of Mysqli and PDO... but when I look at php.net I dont understand enough to really know... what questions to ask you know? I am very frustrated as there are not any good resources that break down things at an amateur level. 
Do you guys have _Any_ other resources? Something that can explain things to me? Little things that shouldnt cause a huge issue like ->bind_result() How does it know which result to bind to that? You cant google that because you wont find an answer. Super Frustrated :(